# How to one hot encode sequential data in ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, generator, one-hot-encoding, sequential

I converted some string labels to tokenized sequences.

```
sequences[0]
[3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 3, 7, 11]
```

Each token stands for a specific character, for example 2 for 'b' etc.

Now, to train a neural network, I would like to use the `ImageDateGenerator` to get one hot encoded labels which should look as follows:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]...]
```

Is there a way to do this with the `ImageDataGenerator`? If no, how could I handle this problem instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 3, 7, 11])
b = np.zeros((a.size, 23))
b[np.arange(a.size),a - 1] = 1
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Notice that in the example output the count start from 1 rather than 0, so I subtracted 1 from `a`.

Using `TensorFlow 2.x` you can do the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a = np.array([3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 3, 7, 11])
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(a, num_classes=23)
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! So, there is no way to do it directly in the `ImageDataGenerator`?

Comment: I use `tensorflow 2`, so I'm not familiar in a way of using `ImageDataGenerator` but I added alternative using `tensorflow.keras`

Comment: Thank you! One additional question: Have you worked with sequential data in connection with (convolutional) neural networks before?

Comment: @Tobitor you mean, RNN and CNN together (parallel/serial)?

Comment: Yes, but actually only a CNN. Could we maybe continue in chat? :)

Comment: @Tobitor sure, no problem